# Why won't my Angular app send params to my Entangle rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, redis, real-time

In an effort to learn about realtime apps, I am trying to create a basic messageboard using [Entangled](https://github.com/dchacke/entangled).

I have an Angular app and a Rails backend with a Messages Controller that includes Entangled::Controller. This Rails controller successfully receives a request when a form is submitted from the Angular app - the form is submitted using Entangled. (On clicking submit, a function is triggered in an Angular controller which should create a new message in the backend and update all clients subscribed to that backend.)

I know the Angular function is being triggered on clicking submit, and I know the function receives the correct information from the form: `console.log($scope.message)` displays `{socket: "ws://message-board-olliehm.c9users.io:8080/messages", username: "ggg", content: "gggggg"}` where I submit "ggg" in the username field and "gggggg" in the content field.

The problem is that these fields are not arriving at the Rails controller. When I click submit, the correct action is triggered in the Rails controller, but the params don't contain the right information: `p params` in `def create` returns `{"controller"=>"messages", "action"=>"create"}`, with no "message" hash and no "username" or "content" keys.

I cannot work out what Entangled is doing with the username and content fields.

Redis is new to me so I'm not sure if the problem is there. I have Redis installed and the redis-server is running as required by Entangled. I have a redis initializer as below, which in the Rails console is successfully connecting and letting me put data in the database:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => $IP, :port => 6379)
```

Here's my Angular controller:

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers');

controllers.controller('MessageboardController', ['$scope','Message', function($scope,Message){

  $scope.message = Message.new();

  $scope.post = function() {
    console.log($scope.message);
    $scope.message.$save(function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.message = Message.new();
      });
    });
  };

  Message.all(function(err, messages) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.messages = messages;
    });
  });

}]);
```

Message here refers to this factory:

```
messageboard.factory('Message', function(Entangled){
  return new Entangled('ws://message-board-olliehm.c9users.io:8080/messages');
});
```

And here's my Angular view:

```
<h1>Messageboard</h1>

<section class='row' ng-if='messages'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='message in messages'>
      {{message.username}}
      {{message.content}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class='row'>
  <form ng-submit="post()">
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='username'>Message as</label>
      <input ng-model='message.username' name='username' type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <input ng-model='message.content' name='message' type='text' placeholder='Write your message here'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Advice would be hugely appreciated - this has caused prolonged frustration and I'm very keen to get stuck into creating something with realtime updates.

Comment: I now have the realtime updates working - but the angular form still isn't submitting any params to the backend so all messages are blank. The form: 
<form ng-submit="addMessage(message)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message.username">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message.content">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
When I console.log that message argument, I get this object: 
(e {socket: "ws://message-board-olliehm.c9users.io:8080/messages", username: "o", content: "o"})
but actually username and content are 'null' on clicking the little arrow to see the object in detail.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error I realised the empty params apparently received by the backend controller were misleading. The params arrive properly and a new message object is created and broadcast as long as I do the following to the raw params the controller receives:

```
params.require(:message).permit(:content,:username)
```

i.e. exactly what you'd do with the form params arriving as you'd expect. The weird thing for me was that params doesn't include a 'message' hash until you require that hash as above. I guess this is something to do with it not being a regular http request, though a proper explanation would be appreciated...